# Where can I find documentation on the LEGO Wireless Protocol for Powered Up devices?

Tags: programming, powered-up, boost

LEGO BOOST and LEGO Powered Up Smart Hubs use Bluetooth Low Energy to communicate to apps. Where can I find documentation on the communication protocol so that I can build my own app for these devices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LEGO calls this communication protocol the "LEGO Wireless Protocol" (LWP). The documentation is publicly available at https://lego.github.io/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs/.

There is also a GitHub repository that provides the source of this website at https://github.com/LEGO/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs. Because of this, it seems reasonable to expect this documentation to evolve over time.

Comment: Note: WeDo 2.0 is similar, but not the same. The official WeDo 2.0 SDK can be found at https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/wedo-2/developer-kits.

Comment: It is too bad that this is the *only* thing LEGO has on github.

Comment: check this repositories also https://github.com/cpseager?tab=repositories - he have few nodejs/python bindings, protocols descriptions and so on